# Powershell script stuck when targeting file in get-ChildItem and not when targeting them in the IF statement

Tags: powershell

I'm very new to Powershell scripting.

I have a script that examines PDF files in a folder and deletes (in the recycle bin, I've installed the recycle module) those with specific names and that are older than x minutes.

```
$directoryPath = $monitored

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$monitored\*.pdf" -Recurse -Force

foreach ($file in $files) {
Write-Host $file.Name -ForegroundColor Green
    if (
        ($file.Name -like "multiple_shipments_labels_merged_*.pdf" -Or
        $file.Name -like "label_*.pdf" -Or
        $file.Name -like "documenti_doganali_*.pdf" -Or
        $file.Name -like "label-*.pdf") -and
        $file.LastWriteTime  -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-2880)
    ) {
        Remove-ItemSafely $file
        Write-Host "Sent $($file.FullName) to the recycle bin."
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "No files found."
    }
}
```

It works like a charm. I want to target my files by their names in the Get-ChildItem expression, since I want the foreach to cycle only through the items with those names and not through each .pdf file.

I changed it like this:

```
# Define the directory path where the files are located
$directoryPath = $monitored

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "$monitored" -Filter "*.pdf" -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { 
    $_.Name -like 'multiple_shipments_labels_merged_*.pdf' -or
    $_.Name -like 'label_*.pdf' -or
    $_.Name -like 'documenti_doganali_*.pdf' -or
    $_.Name -like 'label-*.pdf'
}

foreach ($file in $files) {
    Write-Host $file.Name -ForegroundColor Green
    if ($file.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-2880)) {
        Remove-ItemSafely $file
        Write-Host "Sent $($file.FullName) to the recycle bin."
    } else {
        Write-Host "No files found."
    }
}
```

It actually cycles only through the right files. However, when the if statement is true and it should delete the file, the whole cycle gets stuck and does nothing.

Why? What's wrong with it?

Thank you

Comment: Seems to me the `Remove-ItemSafely` function requires the `$file.FullName` as **string** for its first parameter; not the FileInfo **object**. PS. I would use `(Get-Date).AddMinutes(-2880).Date` to compare the files LastWriteTime against in order to have that date fixed to midnight

Comment: What version of powershell and modules are you using?    
With powershell 7.4.1 and recycle 1.5.0 it works as intended on my system.    

Also, depending on your needs, evaluate using  `.AddDays(-2)` or `.AddHours(-48)`: they makes much more human-readable how much back in time you are checking.